# How to make a ping-pong discord bot with websocket in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, websocket, discord

Im trying to make a simple ping-pong discord bot in Nodejs without any lib like discord.js in Nodejs

I think that using websockets with the rest api of discord is the best solution but I cant find any help or any code example to do it

I found this course : https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/17au/exploration/websockets/slides.html#/
with this "solution" that I can't understant : https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/17au/exploration/websockets/solution/

And this is an extract from the course :

```
const BOT_TOKEN = "xxx";

// Discord Gateway url
const GATEWAY_URL = "wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json";

// Websocket object
let ws = null;

connect();

// connect to gateway
function connect() {
    ws = new WebSocket(GATEWAY_URL); // opens the websocket connection and creates WS object
    ws.onmessage = messageHandler; // on message event
    ws.onclose = connect; // reopen websockets when closed by discord
}
```

What I want to do can be simply done with this code using discord.js :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('ready', function () {
  console.log("Connected !")
})

bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'ping') {
    message.reply('pong !')
  }
})

bot.login(token)
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm the one who provided this talk. While the lecture code does interact with Discord, it is not the most optimal method of doing so. Personally I would suggest using discord.js to create a bot that would respond to your ping.

For reference, the lecture I demonstrated in class is to showcase the functionality of websockets. It is executed within the browser and not with the help of node.js.

Under the hood, discord.js handles connection to Discord websocket gateway well. It responds to things like heartbeats and make sure Discord gateway does not boot the client from inactivity. The code I have demonstrated in lecture can only run for about 30 seconds at a time before being booted from Discord for inactivity.

However, if you are curious about the lecture, the session from Spring 18 is recorded live and can be viewable [here](https://youtu.be/1eIfvqoyZJM).

I hope this help!